# How to guide for creating a uPNP iPhone app?

Tags: .net, iphone, windows, upnp

I want to create an iPhone app that manages a Windows computer via uPNP. The Windows computer will be the device I'm controlling, and the iPhone will be the controller.

I've pretty much narrowed it down to uPNP as my solution of choice, with Platinum uPNP being the library. My question is, how do I implement this? Is there a simple tutorial or sample source code for creating an iPhone uPNP control point with Platinum uPNP? (Or any other library for that matter)

Answer (score 1):

A simple 6 step tutorial, it is not for platinum but the UPnP steps are the same:

http://code.google.com/p/upnpx/wiki/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with uPNP.  However, in abstract terms, doing this on iPhone should be no different from doing it from another Windows computer or any other device/computer.  I imagine that you'll be opening some sort of connection to the controlled device, then following some sort of protocol to do the controlling.

So what you **really** need is:

- Any tutorial/sample code to do any sort of uPNP controller.
- Ask questions about the parts on which you get stuck (*i.e.*, having trouble with the connection?  Having trouble with the protocol?  All the logs look good, but nothing's happening?  Having trouble with basic iOS UI elements?  Etc.)

Sorry, not really a direct answer, I know, but I hope it's helpful, anyway.